# How to add a textbox value to a userarray in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got a n number of textbox values which i able to fetch it through a variable ...My question is that i got a array the source is shown below

```
 for ($x = 1; $x <= $num; $x++) {

     $userArray[] = $this->input->post("select" . $x . "");
     $quantity = $this->input->post('Quantity'.$x);
     $quantity = $quantity.(" "); 
     echo $quantity;
```

**output of quantity is 12345 000000 12345**

```
    }
    if (is_array($userArray) && !empty($userArray))
 {
foreach ($userArray as $user)
{
  $row = explode(',', $user);
  echo implode(",",$row);
 // print_r($row);
  $productName = (isset($row[0]) ? $row[0] : '');
 // print_r($productName);
```

**OUTPUT  3 IN 1 INCENSE STICKS JAI GANESH,3 IN 1 INCENSE STICKS JAI GANESH,3 IN 1 INCENSE STICKS JAI GANESH,**

```
  $barcode = (isset($row[1]) ? $row[1] : '');
 // print_r($barcode);
```

**OUTPUT  683988 683988 683988**

```
  $quantity = $this->input->post("Quantity" . $x . "");
 // print_r($quantity);
```

**THE PROBLEM ARISES HERE OUTPUT COMES LIKE Quantity1 Quantity1 Quantity1**

```
     $flag = $this->cartmodel->productCategory($category);
    // print_r($flag);
  }
  }
```

i need the output of quantity to be added in the user array.. how to achieve this.. thanks for ur time

**final output should be**

```
3 IN 1 INCENSE STICKS JAI GANESH 683988 12345

3 IN 1 INCENSE STICKS JAI GANESH 683988 000000 

3 IN 1 INCENSE STICKS JAI GANESH 683988 12345
```

Comment: You should show exmple definition of input arrays and what is that you want achieve. Additionally, don't use different cases, when asking about quantities, as you have "Quantity" and "quantity", that could mess up a code.

Comment: What `$quantity = $quantity.(" ");`(line5) in your above code means??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $num; $x++) {
    $userArray[] = $this->input->post("select" . $x . "");
    //$quantity = $this->input->post('Quantity' . $x);
    //$quantity = $quantity . (" ");
    //echo $quantity;
    //output of quantity is 12345 000000 12345
    if (is_array($userArray) && !empty($userArray)) {
        foreach ($userArray as $user) {
            $row = explode(',', $user);
            echo implode(",", $row);
            // print_r($row);
            $productName = (isset($row[0]) ? $row[0] : '');
            // print_r($productName);
            //OUTPUT 3 IN 1 INCENSE STICKS JAI GANESH,3 IN 1 INCENSE STICKS JAI GANESH,3 IN 1 INCENSE STICKS JAI GANESH,

            $barcode = (isset($row[1]) ? $row[1] : '');
            // print_r($barcode);
            //OUTPUT 683988 683988 683988

            $quantity = $this->input->post("Quantity" . $x . "");
            // print_r($quantity);
            //THE PROBLEM ARISES HERE OUTPUT COMES LIKE Quantity1 Quantity1 Quantity1

            $flag = $this->cartmodel->productCategory($category);
            // print_r($flag);
        }
    }
}
```